Craft IIS Web Config Rule - Querystring Looping and Encoding/Unencoding
I have a web app that uses a Craft plugin, which displays data from an external API and sets up links with querystrings for pagination.
We recently migrated to a new webserver, where all settings, versions, etc., are the same, with the exception of the webserver, itself, being Windows Server 2022.  The load time of the website has been really irregular, having slow loads of up to 6 sec and fast loads of around 1 sec.  The IIS Process Monitor zeroed in on these pages mentioned above, which were at the HTML Rewrite Module in IIS.
The process monitor is listing these pages, which have rather unusual permutations of the original querystring structure:
For example, the correct URL structure would be:
/directory/bill-smith?purchase_page=2&inventory_page=3

while the incorrect URL structure that may appear (or variations thereof - with a mix of encoded and unencoded characters):
/directory/bill-smith?purchase_page=2%3Finventory_page=3%3Fpurchase_page=2&inventory_page=3

I began wondering if there was some conflict with the querystrings and the way Craft handles them, and the IIS Rewrite Module.  The people who made the website included the web_config file like below.  The "match" and then the "rewrite" lines make me wonder how the back-reference is being applied?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?p={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
<defaultDocument>
    <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.php" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="index.html" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>

